# Alexa Node.js skill not getting into intent

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Developing a demonstration where I am going to control a hardware by voice command, followed a Node.ja sample that works fine when I test in Service Simulator, but When I come to echo dot the intent not gets identified, think I am missing session, I am not sure how could I do it here

this is index.js

```
"use strict";
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
var appId = "amzn1.ask.skill.91bca194-194a-4ca8-92c1-XXXXSDE";


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = appId;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};

var handlers = {
    "LaunchRequest": function () {
        this.emit(':tell', 'Welcome home');
    },

    "CloseIntent": function () {
        console.log("Gets into CloseIntent");
        this.emit(':tell', "The gate is closed");
    },

    "OpenIntent": function () {
        console.log("Gets into OpenIntent");
        this.emit(':tell', "The gate is open");
    },

    "HelloIntent": function () {
        this.emit(':tell', "Hello Welcome ");
    },

    "AboutIntent": function () {
        this.emit(':tell', "The ONLY complete products");
    }
};
```

and this is my intent Schema

```
 {
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "HelloIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "OpenIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "CloseIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AboutIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you didn't provide enough sample utterances for your intents?

Comment: I provided sample utterances, I got the issue solved, it is actually I missed the invoke name

Comment: Just a TIP: `alexa.APP_ID` should be `alexa.appID` as per docs

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you emit a `tell` response, `ask-node-sdk` will include  `"shouldEndSession": true` in the response JSON which will in turn end the current session. Instead of `tell` use `ask`, which will include `"shouldEndSession": false` and will wait for a user response.

```
'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {    
     this.emit(':ask', 'insert speech here', 'insert re-prompt here');
},
```